# Python3 with PyQt5 on Win10 ignores font settings

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, fonts, pyqt5

In my program [GeigerLog](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geigerlog/) I use a fixed width font for some easy formatting of tabular data. Works fine in Linux, did work fine in Windows, but recently I got problems in Win10.

This is what some output looked like on Win and Linux, and still looks like on Linux:

[image]

but this is what it now looks on Windows10:

[image]

Obviously, an (unknown) proportional font is used, and the formatting is gone. And yet, the Python code wrongly confirms that even on Win10 'Courier New' is used. Which is what is desired, but it ain't so!

I tried Python 3.7.3, then Python 3.8.6, and tried the last 5 versions of PyQt5 (5.14.0, 5.14.1, 5.14.2, 5.15.0, 5.15.1) - all showed the same wrong behavior.

Below is a code excerpt for the relevant portions, with the print output added as comments. I define the font, apply it to the NotePad widget, and check this widget with fontInfo(). The proper fixed-Width font is confirmed, also on Win10.

However, this is not what is used on Win10, see screenshots above.

What is going on? Whom do I need to convince to behave, is it Win10, Python3, or PyQt5? And how?

```
import platform
print("platform()",        platform.platform())        # -> Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
print("machine()",         platform.machine())         # -> AMD64
print("architecture()[0]", platform.architecture()[0]) # -> 64bit

#QMainWindow class
...
# font standard
    self.fontstd = QFont()
    self.fontstd.setFamily('Monospace')
    self.fontstd.setFixedPitch(True)
    self.fontstd.setPointSize(10)
    self.fontstd.setBold(False)
    self.fontstd.Weight(QFont.Black)
...
# NotePad
    self.notePad = QTextEdit()
    self.notePad.setFont(self.fontstd)
...
    print("family():",     self.notePad.fontInfo().family())     # -> Courier New
    print("fixedPitch():", self.notePad.fontInfo().fixedPitch()) # -> True
```

Comment: try it:  `self.fontstd = QFont("Consolas", 10)`

Comment: No, that did not work. Neither did defining "Courier New" as font, and I verified that both are on the system and can be used.
But it gave me an idea for further testing with surprising result; too complex for comment, I will make a post.

Answer (score 0):

While @S.Nick's comment did not work, it made me do some test with surprising results.

Using just these 3 lines for the fonststd definition:

```
self.fontstd = QFont("Consolas", 10)
self.fontstd.setFamily('Monospace')
self.fontstd.setFixedPitch(True)
```

results in a wrong proportional font, yet PyQt5 telling me it uses Courier New. The exact same outcome as using QFont empty, like `self.fontstd = QFont()`.

Removing the line with Monospace:

```
self.fontstd = QFont("Consolas", 10)
self.fontstd.setFixedPitch(True)
```

and I get a fixed width font, which PyQt5 says is Consolas! Using again an empty `QFont()` and I am back to a proportional font, and PyQT5 pretending it is Courier New.

Using a proportional font like 'Times':

```
self.fontstd = QFont("Times", 10)
self.fontstd.setFixedPitch(True)
```

and so the second line being in conflict with the first, a fond Times (or like Times) is used, yet PyQt5 still pretends it is showing Courier New!

Using only the line:

```
self.fontstd = QFont("Consolas", 10)
```

a fixed width font is indeed being used, and PyQt5 says it is Consolas.

So, somewhere is a bug; my guess it is in PyQt5?

As a workaround I now need to distinguish between Windows and Linux (and Mac?), which is something I hoped could be avoided with Qt.